# Cant change file permissions for External Drive- Steam Related

Tags: usb, steam, drive

I use Chrubuntu and I have a extremely small amount off space on my computer I want to download steam but dont have enough space for my games. I heard you could download games onto a External Drive so i tried to but it wont allow me to change the file permissions. Does anyone know why and how to fix it. Please help Im pretty desperate

Comment: Steam needs permission changes?

Answer (score 0):

Probably your external drive is formatted as FAT32. That doesn't have the permissions.

If you don't care much about the interoperability with other OSes, reformat the external drive to ext4.